# Vagrant add box gives error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I'm new to Vagrant, I'm using Windows 10. I installed the latest version of Vagrant (1.8.5) and whenever I run command "vagrant add box" in my project root directory, it generates error:

```
"There was an error loading a vagrantFile. THe file being loaded and error Message are shown below:
Path: D:/Projects/My_Project_name/VagrantFile
Line Number: 12
Message: LoadError: Cannot load such file -- D:/Projects//My_project_name/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb"
```

Comment: Try to change the codepage in your cmd before running the command: `chcp 65001`

Answer (score 0):

Command **vagrant add box** doesn't exist. Correct command is **vagrant box add [options] < name, url, or path >**. Use **vagrant box add -h** for more information about this command.